# Wordpress plugin for static text slider

Tags: php, wordpress

I want one slider in wordpress which will create the slider with static text but inside that image will slides. And that plugin must be created short code I want to use that code in my theme.

Comment: Please ask concrete questions, show the work you have done to resolve your problem and the results you got from your work. Right now, your question is basically you describing what you want somebody else to build.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Nik, we're not your personal picking-team. We're here to answer questions related to code you've tried or have questions on, this is quite a broad and personal topic.

Comment: Hi @Nikhil, it would really be helpful for the community to answer queries that are concrete in nature and try to solve specific problems. You should try to
- Be explanatory in queries
- If possible include references of what all have you tried.
This will make questions more reasonable and answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cyclone slider plugin:

[Cyclone Slider 2](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cyclone-slider-2/)